# dB of squeezed light is equivalent to how much squeezing in different directions?

Tags: optics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, photonics

In many structures, the amount of squeezed light is expressed in dB. I wanted to know what is meant by squeezed light in dB.
For example, 10 dB of squeezed light is equivalent to how much squeezing in different directions?
What other scales is this equivalent to?

Answer (score 0):

10 dB means  a factor of 10 because 1dB is a factor $10^{1/10}$, and 10 db is a factor of $(10^{1/10})^{10}=10$.  I assume therefore that the squeezing factor is such that the amplitude one of the quadratures is a factor a 10 larger than the other.

Comment: "dB" is usually defined for power ratios, $10\text{log}_{10}\frac{P_1}{P_0}$, if amplitude ratios, $P \propto A^2$ then it should be $20\text{log}_{10}\frac{A_1}{A_0}$.

Comment: I see that there is a good answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411786/how-much-can-we-currently-squeeze-light